# how to double count a product on wordpress woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need to make double count the product at a time.
For example, when I open a product, it needs to show 0 item chosen. And when I click plus (+), it needs to add 2 at a time. How can I do that on wordpress woocommerce?

Comment: Are you using any purchased them or customize your woocommerce or theme?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Good day, Timur.
As I understand you want to add the Product twice to the cart and show number "2"?
You can use this WC hook:

```
add_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'custome_add_to_cart');
function custome_add_to_cart() {
global $woocommerce;

$product_id = $_POST['assessories'];

$found = false;

//check if product already in cart
if ( sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) {
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
        $_product = $values['data'];
        if ( $_product->id == $product_id )
            $found = true;
    }
    // if product not found, add it
    if ( ! $found )
        WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
} else {
    // if no products in cart, add it
    WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
}
}
```

And when it return the result, update with JS the number of ordered products.

Tell please if it can help you?

Comment: No, I am sorry it is not something I am looking for.

Comment: When you enter an online shop you will see products right. And you click one product that you want to buy. And then that product page will be opened. And there you will see the product image, describtion, price, add to cart button and whatnot.  And there is also the + and - buttons to choose how many products to buy. Normally, you can add product one by one. But I want it to count double when I press + sign, like 2, 4, 6... etc.

Comment: I see. Sorry maybe smbd else can answer you here...

Comment: @TimurNabijonov You can use the following plugin to achieve **step quantity increment**.
[https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-min-max-quantity-step-control-single/]